# How would I add CSS styling to the current Vue.js template?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, components

I have started learning Vue.js and so far, I understand that that styling child components can be done by referring to the classes, ids and tags defined in the component's `template`. Take the following `App.vue` component as an example:

```js
<style lang="css" scoped>
    .app__wrapper {
        width: 90vmin;
        height: 90vmin;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
</style>

<template>
    <MainHeader class="app__header" />
    <ContentWrapper class="app__content-wrapper" />
    <MainFooter class="app__footer" />
</template>
```

How would I go about adding styles to the `App` component itself? I tried the following two ways I could think of, but they didn't seem to work:

```js
<!-- App.vue -->

<style lang="css" scoped>
    App {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .page__app {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
</style>
```

I tried searching other questions on StackOverflow, but only found questions about other web frameworks.

Thanks in advance :) Have a wonderful week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.vue is typically your root component that your Vue instance [mounts](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app) to via `app.mount(#app)` (typical of all default Vue installs).  So you can consider `<div id="app">` to be your root element, this is the element you actually want to target.

The thing about `<style>` is that when [scoped](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) it can only affect CSS belonging to elements of the current component only.  If *not* scoped, the styling will be applied globally.

Using all of the above information, you can target `<div id="app">` using an unscoped style in your App.vue

```css
<style>
#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  ...
}
</style>
```

App.vue being your root component is usually the best place to apply global unscoped CSS like this. It's usually best to keep other component styles scoped unless you have a good reason not to.